# How do I say "/" in a presentation?

Tags: pronunciation

Do I say "Slash" or do I just ignore the / all together? I have a powerpoint presentation coming up and I can't figure out how to say / for my presentation.

Comment: What's context? Can you give an example of a sentence with `/` in it?

Comment: @GEdgar That's asking about the pronunciation in a specific context. The pronunciation is different depending on the context.

Comment: Saying "slash" is like saying "quote" or "comma" or "dash" or "parenthesis" or "full stop". It's unusual or informal. You should not normally read punctuation aloud.

Answer (score 0):

In contexts where the virgule or "oblique stroke" mark is used to express a choice between two alternatives, it's standard in AmE to just say "slash":

> **slash** ( / ) — technically known as a virgule but also called a slant, solidus, or stroke (the common name in British English)—serves a number of purposes in writing, essentially standing in for other words as a quick and clear way of showing the connection between two things. A slash is conventionally used without spaces between it and the words it connects (although it is also common to see spaces used, especially if one or both of the things being joined contain multiple words).

This kind of language is commonly employed in AmE business jargon. Consider "buyers/sellers" in written form:

> The targets for buyers/sellers of the product will increase by 10% in 2020.

which is expressed orally as

> The targets for buyers slash sellers of the product will increase by 10 percent in 2020.

Comment: I'd add that if you are trying to describe the character itself, usually relating to typing it on a computer, it is common to call it a "forward slash". 

For example, when speaking out a URL, you would say "forward slash". This is as opposed to the backslash \ which is used when specifying, for example, a Windows folder location (C:\ProgramData\).

This is as opposed to the more common use Robusto mentioned, e.g., "she is a writer/editor," which should be "writer-slash-editor" when spoken.

Comment: *Slash* is certainly the standard term to use for this symbol when dictating, or when it is otherwise important to convey exactly what appears in printed text, but is it really standard to use it in ordinary oral communication? Is it really more common to say 'and slash or' than 'and or'? Note that other punctuation marks are not normally spoken out, unless one is dictating.

Comment: @jsw29 - Perhaps not common in formal speech, but "slash" is often said informally, in place of "and":  "He is a programmer slash writer."

Comment: @HotLicks, true, but the OP's question is whether *slash* should be spoken out or not in a 'powerpoint presentation', which suggest a somewhat formal setting.

Comment: @HotLicks: Hah, I see I left that out. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say "slash," but I've been known to say "or" or "and" when I deem either appropriate. (Articulating "or" and/or "and" is easier than "slash.") The irony that I'm using "and/or" in my answer is not lost on me.